# "No Element Found" trying to make AJAX send / receive string to PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I read an AJAX tutorial on W3Schools, made a simple example that is basically the same thing, and it produces an error. The tutorial was here if curious: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

I wanted to send a string to a PHP file (similar to the third code block in the link) but I am getting an error: "*No element found*". Firefox highlights line 5 of the PHP file which is just `?>`.

The file with the AJAX code is named "getHello.html" (is .html correct?) and has this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AJAX Hello World Example</title>
    <script>
        function sayHello(str) {
            if (str.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("showText").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
                return;
            }
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("showText").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "sendHello.php?q="+str, true);
            xmlHttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="textIn" onkeyup="sayHello(this.value);"/><br/><br/>
    <div id="showText"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file is named "sendHello.php" and has this code:

```
<?php
    $q = $_GET["q"];
    $response = "Hello World! Sent: ".$q;
    echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Don't mention w3 around here. Might get hurt.

Comment: Are you actually running a PHP server? If you visit `sendHello.php` do you see the code or just the response?

Comment: I was going to snuggest the same thing. Also where does your `"No element found"` error occur. On the html page or the php page? From your question is sounds like your php page.

Comment: Wow, that was really silly. It worked just fine running through MAMP, thank you

Comment: You are echoing input data directly out into an HTML document, this makes you vulnerable to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: @Quentin How should I send the response back?

Comment: The line Firefox references is the line number in the *generated HTML*, not the PHP source file, which Firefox knows nothing about. Do View > Source if you want to see what line it's actually referring to.

Comment: I was running as Preview with BBEdit (before I realized I should be testing with MAMP). Maybe it is different somehow, but it definitely gave me the line of the PHP file when running the HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code worked fine for me. Refresh the page and if you're running on server you control and it still doesn't work, restart the server too (you never know, maybe you have some sort of server-side caching turned on). And yes, .html is the correct extension for getHello.html, since it doesn't contain any PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

With a local server and HTML editor, you can get this error (on the error console) when you forget that you're running the HTML through the file: protocol